# keyword matching and keyword counts

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, count, pattern-matching

I have a dictionary and a list which look like this:

```
key_labels = {'countries': ['usa','france','japan','china','germany'], 
              'fruits': ['mango', 'apple', 'passion-fruit', 'durion', 'bananna']}

docs = ["mango is a fruit that is very different from apple", 
        "i like to travel, last year i was in germany but i like france.it was lovely", 
        "mango bananna and apple are my favourite", 
        "apples are grown in USA", 
        "fruits have the best nutrients, particularly apple and mango", 
       "usa and germany were both in the race last year"]
```

what I'd like to do is check the strings in docs for the presence of keywords(values) from `key_labels` and if those keywords are present, then assign that sentence a label which is basically the corresponding key from the `key_labels` and i can accomplish this by doing:

```
temp = []
for s in docs:
    for k, l in key_labels.items(): 
        for w in l:
            if w in s.lower():
                temp.append({s:k})
```

the output of this looks something like this:

```
#temp
[{'mango is a fruit that is very different from apple': 'fruits'},
 {'mango is a fruit that is very different from apple': 'fruits'},
 {'i like to travel, last year i was in germany but i like france.it was lovely': 'countries'},
 {'i like to travel, last year i was in germany but i like france.it was lovely': 'countries'},
 {'mango bananna and apple are my favourite': 'fruits'},
 {'mango bananna and apple are my favourite': 'fruits'},
 {'mango bananna and apple are my favourite': 'fruits'},
 {'apples are grown in USA': 'countries'},
 {'apples are grown in USA': 'fruits'},
 {'fruits have the best nutrients, particularly apple and mango': 'fruits'},
 {'fruits have the best nutrients, particularly apple and mango': 'fruits'},
 {'usa and germany were both in the race last year': 'countries'}]
```

as you can see, from the output what's happening is that for every keyword that is detected in the sentence the labels are assigned that many times for the same sentence.

but what I'd like to get as an output is something like this:

```
{"mango is a fruit that is very different from apple": {"fruits": 2}), 
 "i like to travel, last year i was in germany but i like france.it was lovely":{"countries": 2}, 
 "mango bananna and apple are my favourite":{"fruits": 3}, 
 "apples are grown in USA": {"fruits":1, "countries":1}, 
 "fruits have the best nutrients, particularly apple and mango":{"fruits": 2}, 
"usa and germany were both in the race last year":{"countries": 1}}
```

How would i modify  my code to accomplish this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `temp` a dict and use `dict.setdefault` and `dict.get` methods to set default values for the outer dict and the inner dicts:

```
temp = {}
for s in docs:
    for k, l in key_labels.items():
        for w in l:
            if w in s.lower():
                temp[s][k] = temp.setdefault(s, {}).get(k, 0) + 1
print(temp)
```

This outputs:

```
{'mango is a fruit that is very different from apple': {'fruits': 2}, 'i like to travel, last year i was in germany but i like france.it was lovely': {'countries': 2}, 'mango bananna and apple are my favourite': {'fruits': 3}, 'apples are grown in USA': {'countries': 1, 'fruits': 1}, 'fruits have the best nutrients, particularly apple and mango': {'fruits': 2}, 'usa and germany were both in the race last year': {'countries': 2}}
```